# Deployer 2 applications one host

Tags: angularjs, symfony, deployment, php-deployer

Given:

- Single-page frontend application(angularJS) & API backend service(Symfony3)
- One host for one stage which hosts both the front- & the backend
- Deployer version 6.0.3

The question is: how to be able to deploy both of them using the following format of command: `dep deploy [frontend|backend]`.
The problem now is: you have to describe them as 2 separate hosts, as they use different parameters, `repository` & `deploy_path` at least. Then if you keep them in one file you can't just have 2 tasks for backend & frontend described as so:

```
task('deploy', [
    'deploy:info',
    .
    .
    .
])->onHosts(['[frontend|backend]']);
```

I mean you can, but then in command line you gonna write `dep deploy stage --hosts frontend` & `dep deploy stage --hosts backend` either one of them will fail with error:

```
  No task will be executed, because the selected hosts do not meet the conditions of the tasks.
```

My guess is that it overrides the task itself & will execute the one that stands last.

---

AND OK. I can be have a workaround for that too

```
task('deploy:frontend', [
    'deploy:info',
    .
    .
    .
]);
task('deploy:backend', [
    'deploy:info',
    .
    .
    .
]);
```

This way, will be logical to run it with `dep deploy:[frontend|backend] stage`, BUT since both frontend & backend live on the same server & they both have `deploy_path` parameters for instance, it just overrides the deploy parameters with the last host's configuration in the file.

---

For that matter what I've used is `onHosts()` function with some tweaking on hosts declarations;

```
host('backend')
    ->hostname('host.com')
host('frontend')
    ->hostname('host.com')
```

& 2 tasks defined:

```
task('deploy:[frontend|backend]', [
    'deploy:info',
    .
    .
    .
])->onHosts(['[frontend|backend]']);
```

this way you'll have to deploy as so: `dep deploy:[frontend|backend] stage --hosts [frontend|backend]` which you all agree is nonsensical.

My further guess is to separate deploys into 2 files as `backend.php` & `frontend.php`. `dep deploy stage -f [frontend|backend].php`, but for everyday operations it is inconvenient, like database import/export...

**Please share your opinions or solutions to this problem**

Answer (score 0):

Define tasks: frontend and backend, then you can simply do: dep backend hostname/stage or dep frontend.

The second parameter of the dep command is a task name, not the fixed word deploy.

Comment: not an option, since you'll have to either override tasks you want to use in both scenarios with different names or you have to specify '--hosts'